Auto instrumentation: how to include full URL path and query string not just http.route
Is it possible to get the Open Telemetry auto instrumentation to include the full URL path and query string (i.e. either the full URL or the entire URL after the protocol, host and port) rather than just http.route in a RESTful servlet (server-side request handling) trace?
I find some references to "otel.instrumentation.http-url.include-full=true" in google search results, but I see no mention of this in the latest docs or code for that matter, nor does it seem to do anything.

Yes, this is possible with the OpenTelemetry Incubator extension, see: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/incubator
We are using no-code instrumentation with the java agent (no sdk) and I was able to get the url.full property exported to our Azure backend.
My config yaml file for the HTTP client side metric:
- selector:
    instrument_name: http.client.request.duration
  view:
    attribute_keys:
      - url.full
      - http.route
      - http.request.method
      - http.response.status_code
      - server.address

You could do the same for the server side metric too.
For more info check out the discussion: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/11220
